# Cocos 2d game pause when home button clicked takes time

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am pausing my game when the home button is clicked using the app delegate's applicationWillResignActive method. The pause works fine, but it seems the pause takes some time.When I resume the game, the player has move some distance.

But if I pause the game by clicking the pause button available in the game, it works fine.

The problem occurs only when the home button is pressed. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the fact that the main thread is still executing between the time you press the home button and the time the `applicationWillResignActive` is invoked

Comment: Its no relevant because where and when exactly are you going to stop it ? :) Its the same issue with pausing the game. BTW I am in the final stages of completing an ios game and until this question I was not aware of it but it happens in my game too of course. If I'll find a better way I'll let you know.